# What's the best way to win a police pursuit?

Tags: midnight-club-los-angeles

I am often arrested by the police in Midnight Club: Los Angeles. I try multiple of way to get.
I tried several ways to save myself but I can't. Is there one or more ways to escape?

Comment: I answered my own question to allow others to benefit from my personal tip. If you have another way, I want you to send your tip. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

The only way that works fine for me is to take the highway and to accelerate and go the furthest I can. My car is faster than the police.

From a distance, they're losing my car and they started looking for me. At this point, simply avoid police vehicles using radar / map. After a while they drop and the pursuit ends!

Answer (score 2):

It also works to go into more complicated roads and try to lose the police and when they are on other roads just stop and wait

Comment: When I think I'm far away, I stop and wait, but they always find me. I just lost all the distance I had.

Answer (score 2):

I just follow the interstate around the downtown area and turn off in the big drainage ditch and go back and fourth between end and end, they lose you about two rounds.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do to escape is:

1. Drive to an area where many cars are in traffic.
2. Do your best to avoid the incoming cars.
3. Use your nitro when all cars have been cleared!

You can also drive really fast, **then make a sharp turn to the left or to the right when you can.**

*Notice:* This will **only** work if there is a building or a dead end in front of you (which forces you to make a turn, or you'll crash).

Not only will the police make a **hard crash on the building,** you'll also get an extra clump of time to escape!